# Android Retrofit + GSON - Enum serialization for API calls - Annoying extra quotation marks added

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit, okhttp

This problem (this might be by design, who knows - not simple to find a clear answer, at any rate) occurs in both Android Retrofit 1.9 and 2.0, and with the latest GSON library.

I have an Enum class like such:

```
public enum SomethingType
{
    @SerializedName("first")
    First,
    @SerializedName("second")
    Second
}
```

And using Retrofit (2.0, but same issue with 1.9) along with GSON, I attempt to output the enum instance as such:

```
@Multipart
@POST("things")
Call<ThingResponse> createThing(
        @Part("image") RequestBody image,
        @Part("lat") double lat,
        @Part("lng") double lng,
        @Part("type") SomethingType type);
```

I was expecting the value transmitted to be `first` or `second`.

Instead, something along the way is adding these silly little quotation marks, and the server is receiving values such as `"first"` or `"second"`.

I've even tried using `.registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Enum.class, new EnumApiSerializer())` in my construction of the `Gson` object, but then I hit a dead end and gave up (I'm actually sure I could solve the problem this way, but it feels really dirty to have to register a type hierarchy adapter for Enums when I quite clearly defined the `SerializedName` I wished to use).

So - why the quotation marks? What am I doing wrong, or how can I stop this (unexpected to the uninitiated) behaviour?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Further testing with a `JsonSerializer` type adapter, I see that with the following code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonRepresentation = gson.toJson(src);
return new JsonPrimitive(jsonRepresentation);
```

`jsonRepresentation` is something like `""first""` (with extra quotes inside). Sure, I can strip them here. But what part of the `SerializedName` doesn't Gson understand?? :(

EDIT 2:

Looks like `@Multipart` with Retrofit 2.0 has a much more general problem now: *all* string arguments have extra quotes added.

Another such issue popped up within the last 24 hours:

[Retrofit 2.0-beta-2 is adding literal quotes to MultiPart values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205855/retrofit-2-0-beta-2-is-adding-literal-quotes-to-multipart-values?noredirect=1#comment54246823_33205855)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211304/using-enums-while-parsing-json-with-gson

Comment: @keno - it's really not obvious what you're referring to there. it there a specific explanation there regarding why ```@SerializedName``` is having extra quotes included during Gson serialization? Specific with code.

Comment: @keno also note that this is about serializing; I'm actually having no trouble deserializing from the server. By that I mean that something like ```{"type":"first"}``` from the API is actually working perfectly, and is deserialized to ```SomethingType.First```.