# How to send Form data in retrofit2 android

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Hi i have a json to send to the server (POST METHORD)`{"country":"india","devicetype":"android"}` it is in form data model
like the key for this json is **data**  ie is the server accept it like

`data={"country":"india","devicetype":"android"}` am using retrofit i use Multipart like this

```
@Multipart
@POST("initiate")
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache"
})
Call<UserInfoServerResponse> getUserInfoRequest(@Part(value="data") UserInfo mUserInfo);
```

here **UserInfo** is the json  but am getting fail message from server after that i used FormUrlEncoded methord

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("initiate")
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache"
})
Call<UserInfoServerResponse> getUserInfoRequest(@Field(value="data",encoded = false) String mUserInfo);
```

its out put is also same failure result from server, but the data sending to the server is in the formate

```
data=%7B%22country%22%3A%22india%22%2C%22devicetype%22%3A%22%22%7D
```

My **UserInfo.class**

```
public class UserInfo {


public String country;

public String devicetype;

public UserInfo( String country,String devicetype) {

    this.country=country;

    this.devicetype=devicetype;
}
}
```

My adaptor class

```
RemoteRetrofitInterfaces mService;
    Retrofit mRetrofit;
  HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();

        mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(AppConstant.HOST).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
        mService = mRetrofit.create(RemoteRetrofitInterfaces.class);

   Call<UserInfoServerResponse> api = mService.getUserInfoRequest(new Gson().toJson(mUserInfo));

        api.enqueue(new Callback<UserInfoServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserInfoServerResponse> responseCall, Response<UserInfoServerResponse> response) {

                if (response.body().status != null) {
                    if (response.body().status.equals("success")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "success---");
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed---");

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserInfoServerResponse> responseCall, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }


        });
```

so how can i send the json to server using retrofit successfully i gone through the [retofit document](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) and follow couple of steps but i dont get any result. can any one help me in this

Thank you

Comment: Post your `UserInfo` class

Comment: try add "Accept: application/json" to the headers.

Comment: where is your Retrofit RestAdapter code?

Comment: okey here is my user info class

Comment: please check me answer do the same. i will posting

Comment: @M-D i updated the question

Comment: @Ramz Check output of this line: `new Gson().toJson(mUserInfo)` Did you get JSON ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104830/discussion-between-m-d-and-ramz).

Comment: buddy my key is data
and value is {"country":"india","devicetype":"android"}
how can i send that to server using retofit

Answer (score 31, accepted):

finally i found the solution hope this will help some other

i achieve the solution by using [FieldMap](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/FieldMap.html)

of retrofit.

```
@POST("initiate")
@FormUrlEncoded

Call<UserInfoServerResponse> getUserInfoRequest(@FieldMap Map<String,String> params);
```

and in the Rest Adaptor section  i changed request data from string to Hashmap form like following

```java
Log.d(TAG, "sendUserInfo called");
UserInfo mInfo = new UserInfo("countyname","android");
String request = new Gson().toJson(mUserInfo);

// Here the json data is add to a hash map with key data
Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("data", request);


Call<UserInfoServerResponse> api = mService.getUserInfoRequest(params);

api.enqueue(new Callback<UserInfoServerResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<UserInfoServerResponse> responseCall, Response<UserInfoServerResponse> response) {

        if (response.body().status != null) {
            if (response.body().status.equals("success")) {
                Log.d(TAG, "success---" + response.body());
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed---");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<UserInfoServerResponse> responseCall, Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

});
```

Basilcally what I used **@FormUrlEncoded**  for form data and **@FieldMap**  to put my request JSON as a key value. i got solution by following this method, hope this will help some one :)

Answer (score 1):

The above solution works but is cumbersome to use , a better solution will be to use a converter for @Multipart formData

Please use the bellow code for proceeding with @Multipart FormData
This is because

> ["" is added to your posting strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205855/retrofit-2-0-beta-2-is-adding-literal-quotes-to-multipart-values/36216137#36216137)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Converter;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;

/**
 * Created by kural on 10/27/17.
 */

public class StringConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {
private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("text/plain");

public static StringConverterFactory create() {
        return new StringConverterFactory();
        }

@Override
public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        if (String.class.equals(type)) {
        return new Converter<ResponseBody, String>() {

@Override
public String convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
        return value.string();
        }
        };
        }
        return null;
        }

@Override
public Converter<?, RequestBody> requestBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] parameterAnnotations, Annotation[] methodAnnotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
    if (String.class.equals(type)) {
        return new Converter<String, RequestBody>() {
            @Override
            public RequestBody convert(String value) throws IOException {
                return RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, value);
            }
        };
    }

    return null;

}
}
```

and in your retrofit client add this line

**.addConverterFactory(StringConverterFactory.create())**

```
public class RetroFitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

            /*retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();*/
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(StringConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();


        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me and return a json to obtain new valid Microsoft Azure Token :

**My end point :**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/get-new-token", consumes = {"application/JSON"}, produces = {"application/JSON"})
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<String> getNewToken(@RequestBody String refreshToken) throws IOException {
    JSONObject json = tokenService.getNewTokenByRefreshToken(refreshToken);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(json.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**My getGraphRepository** :

```
public GraphRepository getGraphRepository() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    // Create and configure the Retrofit object
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(" https://login.microsoftonline.com")
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

    // Generate the graph repo
    return retrofit.create(GraphRepository.class);
}
```

**My Token Service :**

```
public JSONObject getNewTokenByRefreshToken(String refreshToken) throws IOException {
    GraphRepository graphRepository = getGraphRepository();

    // My list of -> Key : Value
    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("grant_type", "refresh_token");
    params.put("client_id", this.client_id);
    params.put("client_secret", client_secret);
    params.put("refresh_token", refreshToken);

    RefreshToken data = graphRepository.getRefreshToken(tenantId, params).execute().body();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);

    return json;
}
```

**My GraphRepository :**

```
@POST("/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<RefreshToken> getRefreshToken(
    @Path("tenant_id") String tenant_id,
    @FieldMap Map<String, String> params
);
```

I hope this can help someone.