# Retrofit 2 Multipart POST request sends extra quotes to PHP

Tags: php, android, multipartform-data, multipart, retrofit2

Using Retrofit 2.0.1, there is a call function in my API interface defined in Android App:

```
@Multipart
@POST("api.php")
Call<ResponseBody> doAPI(
  @Part("lang") String lang,
  @Part("file\"; filename=\"image.jpg") RequestBody file
);
```

I send the request like this:

Call call = service.doAPI("eng", imageFile);

where `imageFile` is a `RequestBody` created with a `File` object. The upload image part has no problem, while the `@Part("lang") String lang` part got extra quotes in server.

In PHP side, it is written as follow:

```
$lang = trim($_POST['lang']);
```

which returns `"eng"`. Why there is an extra double quote surrounded the string?

*of course I can strip the trailing and leading double quotes, but it's weird to do so*

---

Related Issue: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1210

Comment: If your project uses Retrofit 2, IMO, you can see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491096/retrofit-multipart-request-required-multipartfile-parameter-file-is-not-pre/36514662#36514662, pls pay attention to `Call<ResponseBody> postFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("description") RequestBody description);`

Comment: Yes, using Retrofit 2. Is it required to use `MultipartBody.Part` ? as `RequestBody` is also working for file upload. What are the difference?

Comment: Ah, I don't mean image part, just mean `@Part("description") RequestBody description` instead of `@Part("lang") String lang`, because this part is your issue :)

Comment: About file part, MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just added another related issue in Github. It seems Retrofit 2 cannot work well with Strings when Gson converter is used.

Comment: Ah yes, I have just tried `String`, it also sent "\"eng\""

Comment: Try using another converter as documentation, `Scalars (primitives, boxed, and String): com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars`

Comment: will try later. now stripped in API side (which is faster) first. thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried, the same issue :(. Pls read more at https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1210

Comment: Yes, I posted the link in the question as well. Potentially a bug.

Comment: This is the proper solution for this "bug": http://stackoverflow.com/a/36216137/2557258

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For your issue, please use as the documentation

> Scalars (primitives, boxed, and String):
>   com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars

So, add `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.0.1'` into `build.gradle` file

Then...

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(API_URL_BASE)
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
    //.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: is this new convertor factory supports other previous gson related or FormUrlEncoded requests or do we need to convert all our request to Mutipart type  . Hope you got what i mean

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class

Comment: @Yazon2006 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343183/retrofit-could-not-locate-converter-for-class-crashing-app

Comment: @BNK So where is the logic? In this answer you suggesting to use ScalarsConverterFactory. I tried it and got IllegalArgumentException. Then you offers me to use GsonConverterFactory. Very clever.

Comment: @Yazon2006 `ScalarsConverterFactory` is for the OP's issue. I don't know if you have the same issue or not. That link is for `IllegalArgumentException`, I think you can find a working answer there. I am not as clever as you, sure!

Comment: @Shubham I think it's only for "Scalars (primitives, boxed, and String)" Pls read more at https://square.github.io/retrofit/ ("CONVERTERS" section)

Comment: @BNK A have the same issue. And your answer does not work.

Comment: @Yazon2006 I suggest that you find how to fix that  `IllegalArgumentException` first, perhaps by using one of the answers mentioned at the link above, or you can search more in Google/SO

Comment: @Yazon2006 you can try with the lastest version. I mean you use `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'` instead of `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.0.1'` inside `build.gradle` file

Comment: @PriyankaSingh sorry bro, I have not developed Android anymore for years

Comment: @BNK hehe, Okie dokie

Answer (score 10):

***Use `RequestBody` for all your parameters. Please go through below code!!***

```
File file = new File(imagePath);
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
MultipartBody.Part imageFileBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("media", file.getName(), requestBody);
RequestBody id = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),addOfferRequest.getCar_id());
ApiCallback.MyCall<BaseResponse> myCall = apiRequest.editOfferImage(imageFileBody,id);
```

---

**Use `RequestBody` class of `Retrofit` instead of String**

```
@Multipart
@POST(ApiURL)
ApiCallback.MyCall<BaseResponse> editOfferImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part imageFile,@Part("id") RequestBody id);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would rather not use a converter, here's what I did to send a multipart request containing an image file, and 2 strings:

```
@Multipart
@POST("$ID_CHECK_URL/document")
fun postMultipart(@Part imageFile: MultipartBody.Part, @Part string2:  MultipartBody.Part, @Part string2:  MultipartBody.Part)
```

And calling it this way:

```
    val body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpg"), file)
    val imageFilePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.name, reqFile)

    val string1Part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("something", "string 1")

    val string2Part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("somethingelse", "string 2")

    service.postDocument(imageFilePart, string1Part, string2Part)
```

Comment: I didn't want to use a converter either and I'm glad this worked for me. Thank you stranger

Answer (score 2):

I faced this on my project today and this is how I solved it. I changed @Part on my string and other primitive values to @Query, and for file (in my case image) i used @Part. Looks like @Query treats strings in a different way compared to @Part.

So my answer to original question would look like this:

```
@Multipart
@POST("api.php")
Call<ResponseBody> doAPI(
  @Query("lang") String lang,
  @Part("file\"; filename=\"image.jpg") RequestBody file
);
```

This should send string values without unwanted quotes.
Sadly, I cant explain why this works, it has something to do with @Part encoding of data.

Comment: thanks you save me. i was facing this issue from last four hours and at the very bottom of this page this answer solve this problem. Thanks again

Comment: this is a good answer because changing the core retrofit might or might not change other things in your project (at least you will be worried for testing)