# RequestBody is always null in android retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to send raw request body in my android project. If I use String for @Body part it contains "" so it is wrong. For solving this problem I used RequestBody for @Body part and create the RequestBody like

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "Test");
```

problem is when I look at retrofit log the request body is 'null' as below:

```
04-08 18:07:20.990 25886-25906/? D/Retrofit: ---> HTTP POST http://TestURL
04-08 18:07:20.990 25886-25906/? D/Retrofit: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
04-08 18:07:20.990 25886-25906/? D/Retrofit: Content-Length: 4
04-08 18:07:20.991 25886-25906/? D/Retrofit: null
04-08 18:07:20.991 25886-25906/? D/Retrofit: ---> END HTTP (4-byte body)
```

I have search alot but cannot find what is the problem! I should mention that I use retrofit 1.9 and cannot switch to 2.x at this moment.

Update (Add Some Code):

```
@Headers("Content-Type: text/plain")
@POST("/GetUserInfo")
void GetUserInfo(@Body RequestBody request, Callback<UserInfo> callback);
```

Comment: show full code ?

Comment: @Caspain which part do you need? I will add the Rest API part now

Comment: Can you add the webservice receiving your request?

Comment: @JeffersonTavares no the webservice is not avaliable for me, and I cannot understand which part of this problem is related to webservice? It is about the client part, Isn't it?

Comment: It might be something related to the webservice that you're trying to access. Let's say, for example, that your request is somehow incomplete, than the webservice may not send a response back, and that could be the reason why you're getting a null value

Comment: I'm gonna post an answer to your question with a piece of code that works nice to me. Just try it and in case it doesn't work, leave a comment and I'll delete it

Comment: @JeffersonTavares thanks, I will test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had to upgrade to retrofit 2.x and the solution on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904477/retrofit-2-multipart-post-request-sends-extra-quotes-to-php) solve my problem. It doesn't need to create RequestBody anymore.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else that experiences this issue, instead of using `RequestBody`, make use of the classes that extend `TypedOutput` such as  `TypedString`, `TypedFile` and `TypedByteArray`.

See `RequestBuilder` line 372, where retrofit checks whether the body is of `TypedOutput`, otherwise it treats the body as a POJO that can be serialized using the standard (eg Json) converter. As such I believe that `RequestBody` should only be used on Retrofit 2.0+

Eg replace

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "Test");
```

with

```
TypedString requestBody = new TypedString("Test");
```